# ML.Net in Web API on azure

Tags: c#, azure, ml.net

I have ml.net model zip file and i use it with asp.net core web api. Locally work everything fine but when i upload it on azure it doens't work. I change all my path's on azure like this:

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables($"%HOME%\\site\\wwwroot\\{formData.FileName}");
```

For model i use it with model name.

User need to upload image, then that image will be saved locally, then use path to the image for model input and model path use for loading model for prediction.

I followed this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/serve-model-web-api-ml-net .

Something doen't work. I think it is something with model and zip file but i don't know how to solve it

**EDIT**
On azure log:
.
.
.

#### HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
Most likely causes:

- IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request 
          and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
- IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
- IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
- The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
- The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:

Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.

Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.

Verify the permissions for the DLL.

Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.

Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click 
.
.
.

Comment: Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: I get 500 error

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to solve my problem :https://developers.de/2019/10/25/hosting-ml-net-in-appservice/